# Consumir métodos de WCF desde mi web arroja: 'Request Entity Too Large'

Tags: c#, wcf, net

estoy creando un WCF con NET 4.7.2 para poder consumirlo desde mi web en NET 5. Al llamar el método que cree, desde un controlador, el cual recibe un objeto con una propiedad que es de tipo byte array, pero al intentar hacerlo me arroja el error 'Request Entity Too Large'

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Leí que esto estaba relacionado al web.config y el maxReceivedMessageSize, el cual modifiqué en base a post que fui leyendo en distintos foros. Pero aún sigue arrojándome el mismo problema. Alguna idea de qué puede ser? Dejo el webconfig de mi WCF.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  <bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="default" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="Transport"></security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>

    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Y el ConfigureServices startup.cs de mi web, donde también agregué unos parámetros que leí que solucionarían este problema.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = "SistemasDelSur.Session";
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddScoped<SessionHelper>();
        services.Configure<FormOptions>(options => options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = long.MaxValue); //or other given limit

    }
```